# Selenium RC log into wordpress only works on IE

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, selenium

i have a strange problem with selenium. For example i want to login into an wordpress account:

```
browser.Type("user_login", "admin");
browser.Type("user_pass", "mypass");
browser.Click("wp-submit");
browser.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
```

in ie it works, but in chrome and firefox only sometimes?
the user_login isn't always filled out, although i always use waitpageforload.

regards

Answer (score 1):

Use this command: `browser.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");` before `browser.Type("user_login", "admin");` too.